# What do @ and # mean in ARM Assembly Language?

Tags: assembly, arm

1. What do the characters `@` and `#` mean in ARM assembly language?
2. What does this function do?

   `add r0, r0, #5`

[image]

Comment: assembly language is specific to the assembler, the program that reads the assembly language.   For example @ is some ugly replacement for a comment in the gnu assembler, normally ; is used as a comment in arm and other assemblers, more widespread, of course each author is free to do whatever they want.   The # as answered below indicates a number for gnu assembler otherwise the number is assumed to be an address, a different instruction.  (which is not valid for add, but is for other instructions).

Comment: The @ indicates you are asking specifically about gnu assembler for arm.

Comment: all of this is documented between the arm documentation and the gnu assembler documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The character `@` starts a comment.

The character `#` can be used for immediates (numbers) or if it stands at the first position of a line the whole line is counted as a comment.

See [here](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/ARM_002dChars.html#ARM_002dChars).

> what does this function do?
>
> add r0, r0, #5

This function adds 5 to the register r0. It is the equivalent to `r0 += 5` or `r0 = r0 + 5` in other languages.

Comment: I believe in arm assembler, the '#' may also start a comment like a shell script if it is [the first thing in the line](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/ARM_002dChars.html#ARM_002dChars).  I don't think you need the '#' and can write just `add r0, r0, 5` as well.  It is always a constant in RISC.  CISC cpus may have trouble as '5' could be an address.  However, `add r0, r0, #5` is probably more programmer friendly.